# XSLT2 Transformation failed

Tags: xml, xsd, mapping, altova, map-force

I have a problem in a part of a function that gives me the error

```
XSLT2 Transformation failed: Error in XPath 2.0 expression (Too many items - fn:string)
```

This is the code line that generates the error:

```
<xsl:for-each select="(fn:doc($cwklic_codeMappings3)/ns0:KLCodeTable)[(fn:string(ns0:codeType/@name) = 'IFTdep')]">
```

And this  is the entire area of that code.

```
<xsl:variable name="var93_resultof_map" as="node()?">
    <xsl:for-each select="(fn:doc($cwklic_codeMappings3)/ns0:KLCodeTable)[(fn:string(ns0:codeType/@name) = 'IFTdep')]">
    <xsl:variable name="var92_resultof_first" as="node()" select="ns0:codeType"/>
        <codeType xmlns="http://www.kewill.com/logistics/klic/conversion">
        <xsl:sequence select="($var92_resultof_first/@node(), $var92_resultof_first/node())"/>
    </codeType>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

And here is a graphical mapping screenshot.

[image]

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this means that a KLCodeTable can have more than one codeType, meaning that the argument to string() contains several attribute nodes.

If you wanted your predicate to evaluate to true if any of the codeTypes had the required value, just drop the call on string(), i.e. write `[ns0:codeType/@name = 'IFTdep']`.

If you meant something else, then you'd better tell us what you meant...

Incidentally, the fn: prefix is quite unnecessary on function calls in XSLT. By all means use it if your productivity is measured by the length of your code, but otherwise it's a waste of space.

Comment: This is the contents of the KLCodeTable: http://i.imgur.com/SFgYso7.png I am also not quite sure if I understand what you mean.  Yes, KLCodeTable contains more than one codeType, but that is why I filter for the name IFTdep. And the prefixse/code are automaticly generated by Altova Mapforce. I have no experience with Xpath/xlst. But I'll try what you have written above.

Comment: My employer does not allow me to manually adjust the generated code. I have tried regardless, but it didn't seem to help. I did, however, change the graphical mapping around in another method, and that seemed to work. Thanks regardless. Should I accept this as an answer aswell?

Comment: I'm afraid I find programming with graphical languages incredibly hard. They're designed for people who think much more visually than I do. So I feel your pain if you're forced to do it this way, but I can't help.